# Using public shared runners

Tags: gitlab-ci-runner

I'm trying to use public shared runner to deploy my code to heroku. My .yml file looks like this:

```
heroku:
  type: deploy
  script:
    - apt-get update -qy
    - apt-get install -y ruby-dev
    - gem install dpl
    - dpl --provider=heroku --app=my-app-staging --api-key=$heroku_api_key
  tags:
    - mysql
    - ruby
    - mongo
    - postgres
 only:
    - DEV
```

The tags are matching those on public runners, but yet none is being picked up and the build is in forever pending status.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the whitespace is off for `only` - and that could certainly be enough to through your pipeline into flux.

Second, the `deploy` stage you have configured will only run on branches and tags named `DEV`. I'd start by committing a `.gitlab-ci.yml` file without the `only` at all.

Finally, even shared runners need to be explicitly added to a pipeline. Navigate to `{your repo}/settings/ci_cd` and make sure that the runner with the tags you need is not laying in wait there.